# Как отправить несколько значений checkbox через $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть 3 checkbox

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="language_check" value="Russian"><p class="language_p">Русский</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="language_check" value="Latvian"><p class="language_p">Латышский</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="language_check" value="English"><p class="language_p">Английский</p><br>
```

ajax:

```
data={ language:$('.language_check:checked').val(),
            action : 'language'};
        $.post('core.php', data, function(response){
            if(response == 1){...
```

При таком раскладе отправляет всегда одно значение, как мне его заставить отправить массив? )

Comment: И что лучше, $.ajax или $.post ?

Comment: `var languages = [];
$('.language_check:checked').each(function() {
  languages.push(this.value);
});

data={ language: languages, action : 'language'};` ?

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать ф-цию `map`, почти как `each`, но возвращает новый массив

Штатный пример:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var squareNumbers = numbers.map(function (index, val) { return val*val });

squareNumbers // [1,4,9,16,25];
```

В вашем случае:

```
data={
    language: $('.language_check:checked').map(function (i, el) {
        return el.value; // тут не JQ объекты
    }),
    action : 'language'
};
```

**P.S.**
Если вы модный и используете ES6

```
...
language: $('.language_check:checked').map( (i,el) => el.value ); 
...
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает, вариант который был в комментариях сработал.

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан, ах, простите, забыл скобочку, теперь не должно быть ошибок

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Answer (score 1):

```js
$.post('core.php', $('#languageForm').serialize(), function(){})
```

```html
<form id="languageForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" class="language_check" value="Russian"><p class="language_p">Русский</p><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" class="language_check" value="Latvian"><p class="language_p">Латышский</p><br>
  <input type="checkbox "name="language[]" class="language_check" value="English"><p class="language_p">Английский</p><br>
</form>
```